# Why are my MySQL queries on large tables with text field extremely slow despite index and supposedly small query times?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, logging, full-text-search

I'm running a MySQL databases and access it through php for my website (LAMP stack). The database is filled with days (=~ separate tables) that contain log data for certain devices. Each row contains some IDs, a timestamp and a text field (up to 200 characters). On that text field, a fulltext index is applied.

My queries are now rather simple and of the following form:

```sql
SELECT [timestamp,ID,text] 
FROM TABLE_FOR_THAT_DAY 
WHERE MATCH(text) 
AGAINST('+ONEWORD' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Having tested the query via a phpmyadmin-interface and via php (without fetching the rows), I can only say the performance is really bad. The tables contain about 100 million rows each, and the result set roughly 500000.

I'm full aware that -for this purpose- a relational database is not the best option, but I can't change this circumstance.

Puzzling to me now is the fact that in the phpmyadmin interface, the query time shows times between 0.5s up to 7.5s, while the actual loading time is 5min+... At first I thought this was due to the fact that this is a remote server and the actual data transfer might take long, but testing it locally via a php-script showed the same results in terms of performance. The machine has 8gb of RAM and a good CPU (Intel Xeon Gold 6140 , 2.3GHz, 8Cores), which is never working at full capacity.

Now the actual questions: Why is there such a strong discrepancy between the shown query time and the actual loading time? Is it memory based? Can I reduce the overall query/loading time (I tried several InnoDB buffer options, but to no effect.)?

Many Greetings

Comment: When you say "loading time", what exactly is happening during that?  Are you actually trying to display/output 500,000 rows?

Comment: Are you aware that finding the records is different from actually fetching the contents? This may explain the discrepancy.

Comment: No, it's the standard LIMIT 0,25. And in my php script, it just queries. Nothing else done. (No fetch_assoc...).

Comment: @TobiasF. Yes. So you would assume a memory issue? In the actual latter steps, I want to use the result and fetch the rows (single rows) for further analysis.

Comment: For clarificaition: I'm not fetching the complete table.

Comment: @NewbieMcJones  In your question, you say "and the result set roughly 500000".  That does not match up with "LIMIT 0,25".  There's a huge difference between a resultset of 500k and a resultset of 25.  You also do not show a `LIMIT` clause in your sample query.

Comment: In my php script, the line "result=database->query(QUERY_FROM_ORIGINAL_POST);" is taking extremely long, though the query time in phpmyadmin shows very short times. Assuming that the query time is different than query and fetch makes it even more puzzling to me, since I'm not fetching a single row in my php script yet, but still it takes forever :).

Comment: Don't think your server has enough RAM for what you need. How big is the entire database and how much RAM have you allocated to MySQL?

Comment: @PatrickQ Ah right: It only shows the first 25 on the standard, but it's not with LIMIT 0,25.

Comment: @cOle2 The complete database is about 3 billion (edited...) rows strong. Each day is in one table with about 100million rows. What do you mean by "allocated to MySQL"? I'm not a MySQL expert by any means... Do you mean some kind of server option?

Comment: @cOle2 If you meant the innodb_buffer_pool_size: I allocated 4G.

Comment: Each table ís about 2-3G big + about 1.2G for the index.

Comment: With that setting if the size of the entire DB is larger than 4GB then your queries will be I/O bound as it won't be able to store it in memory. Here's a link to help figure out what your buffer pool should be: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81106/best-innodb-buffer-pool-size-for-8gb-ram but really you need more RAM if you're adding ~4GB/day and want your queries to be faster.

Comment: @cOle2 But I am only querying on one single day each time. The table for a day is about 4G big... How can there be a memory problem?

Comment: Profile your query, run mysqltuner etc. if you want to see what is sucking up the time. Just because you have a 4GB buffer pool and you query a 4GB table doesn't mean it will fit it all into memory.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size, # cores of your MySQL Host server 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT (your query); will be the best information you could provide for the query that is not acceptable and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE table_for_that_day;  please.

Comment: @cOle2 - No.  A well-indexed query will not need the buffer_pool to be big enough for the entire table and index, only some subset of it.  The OP seems to be fetching less than 1% of the data, and some small fraction of the index.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to try to get the raw query time:

```
SELECT AVG(LENGTH(text)) FROM .. WHERE MATCH ..
```

That will be required to do all the I/O work to *pick* the rows, but not the time to *send* them.

Run that twice -- There could well be I/O caching issues that interfere with understanding how long the query takes.

Please provide the `AVG` returned by the query; it may include another clue.  After all, 500K rows takes a lot of time to send across the wire, and a lot of space to instantiate in PHP.

`FULLTEXT` is the best way to search for such data; don't rush to other solutions.

I am confused as to "query time" versus "load time".  The above query may address the "query time".  However, all 500K rows must be fetched from disk and "loaded" into the server's RAM, then transmitted and "loaded" into the PHP app.  Those are separate servers?  Which machine is phpmyadmin on?

There are two ways to fetch data.  The default for PHP is to pull all 500K rows before letting you do anything with them.  The alternative pulls a few at a time, giving you the *illusion* that it is faster.  In reality, it takes longer to get *all* 500K.

You say "I'm not fetching the complete table".  My point is that it is probably happening inside the PHP API.

Meanwhile, I don't know which method phpmyadmin uses.